# Fast library for parallel n-diagonal matrix inversion

Tags: libraries, banded-matrix

I've tried looking for efficient parallel algorithms to solve banded systems. SPIKE is a good example but it however requires that the band size is large.

Is there any efficient library implementing a parallel algorithm for n-diagonal systems (where n is less than 10)

I haven't found any implementations of Thomas' algorithm which seems promising.